# How to prove the linear map is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck with the proof of [Goldstine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem), here is the step I cannot understand. Let $X$ be a vector space, and $f_i:X\to \mathbb{C}$ ($1\leq i\leq n$) be linear functionals which is linearly independent, then the linear map $X\to\mathbb{C}^n$ defined by
$$ x\mapsto (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))$$ is surjective
is surjective. How to show this?

Comment: $f_1(x),\cdots, f_n(x)$ are elements of $\mathbb C$, so they are never linearly independent. You should find $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_1)\\\vdots\\f_n(x_1)\end{pmatrix},\cdots,\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_n)\\\vdots\\f_n(x_n)\end{pmatrix}$$ are independent.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You are right, my idea is absolutely wong.

Comment: An idea (that I can't put as an answer b/c the question is on hold): The maps $f_i:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ correspond to maps $\overline{f_i}:X/{\ker f}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $\overline{f_i}(x + \ker f) = f_i(x)$, where $f = (f_1,\dots,f_n)$. The functionals $\{\overline{f_1},\dots,\overline{f_n}\}$ are linearly independent, so the dual space of $X/\ker f$ has dimension at least $n$, so $X/\ker f$ has dimension at least $n$. If we let $\overline{f} = (\overline{f_1},\dots,\overline{f_n})$, then $\ker\overline{f} = \{0\}$, so Im$(f) = $Im$(\overline{f})$ has dimension at least $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$ and $S=\{ f(x) | x \in X \} \subset \mathbb{C}^n$.

If $S$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, there is some non zero $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $ \alpha \bot S$. 
Then $\alpha^* f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, or $\sum_k \overline{\alpha_k} f_k (x) = 0$ for all $x$ or $\sum_k \overline{\alpha_k} f_k = 0$, which implies that the
$f_k$ are linearly dependent.
Hence $S$ cannot be a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and hence 
$f$ is surjective.

**Alternative**: This approach avoids dealing with orthogonal complements
but is more tedious and (I think) is less intuitive.

Let $N = \cap_k \ker f_k$ and $Y = X /N$. Note that if $x_1-x_2 \in N$, then $f(x_1-x_2) = 0$ and so $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and so 
$\tilde{f}([x]) = f(x)$ is well defined. Note that $\ker \tilde{f}$ is trivial and ${\cal R} f = {\cal R} \tilde{f}$.

Then $\dim X/N \le n$. To see this, suppose there are $n+1$ linearly independent $y_i = [x_i] \in Y$, and let
$A= \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{f}(y_1) & \cdots & \tilde{f}(y_{n+1}) \end{bmatrix}$, since $A: \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ we see that
there must be some $\beta \neq 0$ such that $A \beta = 0$ , or
$\sum_k \beta_k \tilde{f}(y_k) = \tilde{f}(\sum_k \beta_k y_k) = 0$,
and so $\sum_k \beta_k y_k = 0$ (that is, $N$), hence a contradiction.

Let $y_1,...,y_m$ be a basis for $X/N$ and define
$F=\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{f}(y_1) & \cdots & \tilde{f}(y_{m}) \end{bmatrix}$. Then note that ${\cal R} F = {\cal R} \tilde{f}$. It
is clear that ${\cal R} F \subset {\cal R} \tilde{f}$, and since
$y_1,...,y_m$ is a basis, any $y$ can be written $y=\sum_k \beta_k y_k$ and hence $f(y) = F \beta$ so we have equality.

Now note that the vectors $(\tilde{f}_k(y_1),...,\tilde{f}_k(y_m))$ (the rows of $F$)
are linearly independent. To see this, suppose
$\sum_k \beta_k (\tilde{f}_k(y_1),...,\tilde{f}_k(y_m)) = 0$. Then
$\sum_k \beta_k \tilde{f}_k(y_j) =0$ for all $j$ and hence
$\sum_k \beta_k \tilde{f} = 0$ and so $\beta_k = 0$. Hence $F$ has
at least (in fact, exactly) $n$ linearly independent columns and
hence ${\cal R } F = \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Thanks, you use the fact that a subspace of  $\mathbb{C}^n$ has orthogonal complement. Can we prove it directly? not by contradiction.

Comment: Ordinarily, orthogonality in $\Bbb C^n$ would be stated in terms of the hermitian inner product.

Comment: @TedShifrin: It was an unsuccessful attempt to avoid some notational clutter.

Comment: @XiangYu: I added an alternative approach that avoids using orthogonal complements.

Comment: A slightly easier approach is to invoke duality and reduce to showing that, given linearly independent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ and $a\in\Bbb C^n$, there exists $\phi\in V^*$ with $(\phi(v_1),\dots,\phi(v_n)) = a$. This can be done, for example, by extending $\{v_i\}$ to a basis and using the dual basis.

Comment: @TedShifrin To use this method, I think we need the assumption  $X=X^{**}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Note that $N=\cap_i \ker f_i=\ker f$, so by the first isomorphism theorem , we have $X/N\cong R(f)$, this seems to make the proof easier.

Comment: @XiangYu: I wrote this before I realized your $X$ might be infinite-dimensional. I don't yet see an argument that with $V=X^*$ we are guaranteed that $\phi \in X\subset X^{**}$.